# Why does Jquery ajax add slashes to String?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: How to stop AJAX function escaping JSON string used to POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565887/jquery-how-to-stop-ajax-function-escaping-json-string-used-to-post-data)

I make a jQUERY ajax call to send and save to data.When I send `Google's Dog` string, I receive `Google\'s Dog` . What is the reason of this . And what is the best way yo avoid this. I do not want to use stripslashes function because this removes all backslashes

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://example.com/api/save',
  data: {
    data: userArray,
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
  }
});
```

userArray is an array which has user's information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those slashes are [`escaping`](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/) the special characters. Basically its telling javascript to treat that character as a normal string character instead of something 'special'. Click the link for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered.
[jQuery: How to stop AJAX function escaping JSON string used to POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565887/jquery-how-to-stop-ajax-function-escaping-json-string-used-to-post-data)

Comment: What is the answer ?.If my question is already answered please comment it. Do not write link as a answer.

Comment: You now have 2 posts with the answer in a link, Capt Otis gave you a perfectly good answer, and I am frustrated by your response.

Comment: Please use comments on the question to indicate duplicates, not answers.