# How to stop jQuery ajax from adding slashes to JSON string?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I am sending stringified JSON object to a wordpress action

```
console.log( JSON.stringify(alloptions) );

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: ajaxurl,
    processData: false,
    data: {
        'action': 'create_preset',
        'preset': JSON.stringify(alloptions)
    },
    success: function( response ) {

        console.log( response );

    }
});
```

the console log of the stringified object before sent via ajax is this

http://prntscr.com/7990ro

so the string is correctly processed ,

but on the other side it comes out with slashes

```
function _create_preset(){

    if(!is_admin() && !isset($_POST['preset'])) return;

    print_r($_POST['preset']);

}

add_action("wp_ajax_create_preset", "_create_preset");
```

gives

```
{\"get_presets\":\"eedewd\",\"site_width\":\"1400px\",\"layout_type\":...
```

I know I can use

```
stripslashes( $_POST['preset'] )
```

to clean it up but that is what I am trying to avoid. I need the JSON string to be sent to the action as it is before the ajax, without slashes.

any help is appreciated!

and magic quotes is not on

http://prntscr.com/7996a9

***UPDATE AND SOLUTION**

Jesse nailed it and WP was causing the trouble.
Since the `wp_unslash()` is on its way to fix this in 5.0 
https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/172
I added this to my code

```
global $wp_version;
$new_preset_options = $_POST['preset'];

if ( version_compare( $wp_version, '5.0', '<' ) ) {

    $new_preset_content = wp_unslash( $new_preset_options );

}else{

    $new_preset_content = $new_preset_options ;
}
```

Comment: brrrrrrrr, sounds like magic quotes: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php

Comment: @jeroen no is not , http://prntscr.com/7996a9

Comment: It looks like you're right, but can you confirm that checking the value of `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`?

Comment: did you look at the actual request to see if it's escaped there? (as in, look at browser Net tab or charles proxy or w/e)

Comment: I believe WordPress causes this internally, you might be stuck using stripslashes.

Comment: @jeroen http://prntscr.com/7998g3  ,   I think is connected to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1565913/594423 but I cant process my data with it set to false

Comment: @JesseKernaghan that is what I was afraid off.

Comment: @Benn They pass all global input data through wp_slash, but it looks like that might be patched in 5.0 to be auto unslashed when being requested: https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/172

Comment: @JesseKernaghan that is it , I thought I was  going crazy. Post it as answer please so that I can accept it.

Comment: I cannot find proof that this did make it into WP 5.0 (I only did a little investigation.)  I am running into the same error with wp_unslash, so I am using it despite being on v5.3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

WordPress made the decision a long time ago to auto add slashes to all global input variables ($_POST, etc). They pass it through an internal `wp_slash()` function. The official recommended way to remove these slashes is to use their provided `wp_unslash`:

```
wp_unslash( $_POST['preset'] );
```

[Here is the codex reference.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unslash)

**Note: It looks like this [might be getting fixed in version 5.0](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/172), where they will be doing the `wp_unslash` for you when you request values from the global input variables.

Comment: That was it , just tested on normal php ajax not WP and my string comes out as expected. http://prntscr.com/799kl6

Comment: Thanks, it was useful.

Comment: And what if the json has to contain some "?